# Does twig support grandchildren inheritance?

Tags: php, twig

My web application is structured as follows:

- master.html (contains the master layout for the page)
- page.html (contains the content of an individual page)
- child.html (contains some data that may or may not be loaded)

I've got javascript in the child.html that needs to go beneath my jQuery link in master.html. Does Twig have a tag such that this is possible?

---

Clarifying with an example of sample output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Content of page.html, which has content from child.html within it -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <!-- Scripts from child.html -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You create blocks in the `master.html` template and you can override these in `page.html`, as in `child.html`

*master.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ title | default('Hello World') }}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
        {% block css %}
        {% endblock %}
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        {% block javascript_sources %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
           //default code
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*page.html*

```
{% extends "master.html" %}
{% block javascript_sources %}
    <script src="my.jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
     <script>
         $(function(){
            console.log('-- page loaded --');
         });
     </script>
 {% endblock %}
```

*child.html*

```
{% extends "page.html" %}
{% block javascript %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script>
        $(function(){
            console.log('-- child loaded --');
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm using this now. That works well, but child.html inherits the layout of master.html. I just want to add some JS after my jQuery inclusion. I was in a rush when I wrote the original question, so I'll go back and edit it.

Comment: So page does not extends master?

Comment: page.html does extend master.html.

Comment: There is no real way, not that i have found out anyway, to make an included file change the content of the file that included him at this moment.

Comment: Shoot. I'll see what I can do to get a workaround then. Cheers though!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for anyone who stumbles upon this post at a later date, this is what I ended up doing:

- Outsource all necessary javascript to another file, called `child.js`.
- In the same conditional that determined whether to load `child.html`, load `child.js` into a variable.
- Use twig variables to turn `$js` in PHP into `{{ js }}` in twig. (Be sure to use `{{ js|raw }}` to avoid escaping it) Use this variable in your `page.html` file.
- If `child.html` is not loaded, `$js` contains an empty string.